# Метод выбора порядкового номера ячейки массива

Tags: java

Есть класс телевизор, в нем метод `tvOn` , он принимает на вход число и должен из массива `channels[]` выбрать номер той ячейки которая соответствует этому числу. Не понимаю как описать это.

Код:

```
public class TV {
    String modelTV;
    Channel channnels[];
    RemoteController remote;

    public String getModelTV() {
        return modelTV;
    }
    public void setModelTV(String modelTV) {
        this.modelTV = modelTV;
    }
    public void setChannnels(Channel[] channnels) {
        this.channnels = channnels;
    }
    public void setRemote(RemoteController remote) {
        this.remote = remote;
    }

    public void tvOn(int channelNumber) {

        for (int i = 0, i < channnels.length, i++) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Если он должен выбрать, он должен что-то вернуть? Но у вас метод `void`

Comment: Как вы понимаете "_выбрать_". Вернуть? Или что?

Comment: if (channels[i].number == channelNumber) return i;

Comment: Иначе в не цикла return -1;

Comment: напечатать , включен канал такой, простите за неточность

Comment: Дык, включён канал `channelNumber`  %)

Comment: Класс `Channel` как выглядит?

Comment: Class chanel { String name;Program programs [] }       channels[]  в телевизоре это массив имен каналов . Класс програмс состоит из стринг name.

Comment: То есть вы передаете номер канала, который будет `>= 1 и <= размеру channels`? И вам просто напечатать нужно информацию, что включен такой канал? Если да, то в чем сложность? Просто печатаете, что канал с номером `channelNumber` включен и можете вывести информацию о канале обратившись к нему `channnels[channelNumber - 1]` ( - 1 т.к. номер подразумевает 1, 2, 3 и т.д. может вы передаете индекс 0, 1, 2 и т.д, тогда уже без -1)

Comment: ну скорее я ввожу число от 0 до 100 , и если в массиве  есть не пустой индекс под этим номером то напечатать , включен канал ( содержимое ячекйки ) "Первый канал" например. Что то вроде этого. Я не знаю как обратится к массиву, как его обьявить в методе

Comment: То есть перед тем, как вызываете `tvOn` у вас уже есть заполненный массив `channels` и вам нужно просто проверить, что под таким то номером, есть канал? То есть у вас где то есть например `channnels = new Channel[4]` и в `tvOn` вам нужно, что-то типа такого: `if(channelNumber <= channnels.length) выводите информацию о канале; else канал не найден`??

Comment: ну по сути да, массив заполнен. сначала все проинициализируется, создаются обьекты

Comment: @Mobsman ну тогда `if(channelNumber < channnels.length) System.out.println("Включен канал: " + channnels[channelNumber].name); else System.out.println("Канал с номером " + channelNumber + " не найден!");` и цикл не нужен

Comment: if(channelNumber < channnels.length)  если число меньше длиннны массива то (не понимаю channnels[channelNumber].name описание).  Число 0 он выведет нулевую ячейку?

Comment: @Mobsman 1) `channnels[channelNumber].name` просто обращение к полю `name` канала в массиве `channnels` под индексом `channelNumber`. 2) Если вы передадите `channelNumber < размера массива`, то он выведет "Включен канал: <название канала>" То есть передав 0 он выведет название канала у которого индекс в массива = 0

Comment: подскажите я вот так сейчас додумал, так верно ?                                              
      for (int i = 0 ; i<channnels.length ; i++){
            if (i==channelNumber) {
                System.out.println("Включен канал:"+channnels[channelNumber].name);

Comment: @Mobsman в принципе да, но зачем же цикл использовать? Можно сразу вывести канал, как я писал выше.

Comment: единственное что умею хоть как то

Comment: channnels[i].name  так можно писать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример, как вы хотели с комментариями:

```
public void tvOn(int channelNumber) {
    //Проходим по массиву каналов
    for (int i = 0; i < channnels.length; i++) {
        //Находим канал с индексом channelNumber 
        //(или номер, но это разные вещи и в вашем случае индекс)
        if (i == channelNumber) {
            //Выводим название канала обращаясь к массиву channnels
            //по индеску channelNumber к полю name
            System.out.println("Включен канал: " + channnels[channelNumber].name);
            //Моментальный выход из функции. Т.к. смысла дальше исказть нет
            //если мы уже нашли
            return;
        }
    }
    //Если же выход из функции не произошел, то мы не нашли канал с нужным номером
    System.out.println("Канал с номером " + channelNumber + " не найден!");
}
```

Приведу пример, как можно было написать:

```
public void tvOn(int channelNumber) {
    //Если переданный канал не отрицательный и не больше или равен кол-ву каналов
    if (channelNumber >= 0 && channelNumber < channnels.length) {
        //то выводим канал с номером channelNumber
        System.out.println("Включен канал: " + channnels[channelNumber].name);
    }
    else {
        //Если же номер канала не правильный (< 0) если канала 
        //с таким номером нет, то выводим информацию
        System.out.println("Канал с номером " + channelNumber + " не найден!");
    }
}
```

И да отвечаю на ваш последний комментарий, можно писать `channnels[i].name` это обращение к `i-тому` элементу массива `channnels`.

Comment: просто когда читал про массивы, там всегда используют цикл. Получается к элементам массива абстрактного типа данных можно обращается так  channnels[channelNumber].name

Comment: К любому массиву можно обратиться по индексу `channnels[channelNumber]`, а т.к. у вас массив классов `Channel`, то вы получаете объект типа `Channel` после `channnels[channelNumber]` и можете обратиться к его полю `name`.

Comment: channnels[channelNumber]   разве это не входное число int channelNumber,происходит проверка через иф, и если все нормльно то выбирается индекс=входному числу процедуры?

Comment: `channelNumber` - индекс, `channnels[channelNumber]` - объект типа `Channel` расположенный в массиве `channnels` по индексу `channelNumber`.

Comment: Хотел еще спросить, я хотел добавить еще название канала( он массив) но в печать выводит хешкод вроде, System.out.println("Включен :"+channnels[i].name+" "+"Включена:"+" "+channnels[i].programs);                                                                                
 Включен :Второй канал Включена: [LProgram;@4554617c

Comment: @Mobsman лучше не засорять комментариями этот ответ. Создавайте новые вопросы не стесняйтесь. У вас `programs` это массив. Его нужно выводить поэлементно. В гугле быстро найдете всю информацию или на ruSO